# Implementing a Anti CSRF in my Social Net

Tags: javascript, php, csrf

I developed a social network of video games and I own a security system against csrf based on the user id as a key.

as this is not safe, I need to know how I can implement all my requests POST in a TOKEN field that always send all POST requests

There would be some way to implement this? Maybe with javascript?

Much thanks people :)

Comment: Are you sure you want to *implement* CSRF? Usually people try to *prevent* it and those who do implement usually do it quietly...

Comment: if you don't have any XSS problems, just using POST should be enough.

Comment: Jajaja, sorry for my title xD. I use POST for my request but exist services who convert get queries to post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find this great class for CI: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/protect-a-codeigniter-application-against-csrf/

This library hook all forms in output and insert a hidden field

I use this function to hook this field in all ajax requests

$(document).ajaxSend(function(e, xhr, options) {
  var csrf_token = $("meta[name=csrf-token]").attr("content");
  options.data = options.data+"&"+$("meta[name=csrf-name]").attr("content")+"="+csrf_token;
});

Answer (score 0):

Using `$_SESSION` in something like the below would be a start. `GET` is used instead of `POST` simply for illustrative purposes.

```
<?php
session_start();
if( ! isset($_GET['submit']) ) {
  $_SESSION['crsf_token'] = md5(rand());
  echo 'token set';
} else {
  printf("post: %s - session: %s<br/>", $_GET['token'], $_SESSION['crsf_token']);

  if( $_GET['token'] !== $_SESSION['crsf_token'] ) {
    unset($_SESSION['crsf_token']);
    echo 'CSRF!';
  } else {
    unset($_SESSION['crsf_token']);
    echo 'Not CSRF.';
  }
}
?>
<form action="" method="GET">
  <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<? echo $_SESSION['crsf_token']; ?>" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

The token simply needs to be uniquely generated and stored each time you present a form to the user.

Comment: I have many forms

there is a way to include the TOKEN field in all forms and ajax requests?

Comment: That depends entirely on how your pre-existing code is written.

Comment: this is a example of ajax call method: http://pastebin.com/4zk6pDhn For simple post method i use a usual form